# How to diagnose an abend in CICS using offset number

Tags: cobol, mainframe, jcl, cics

I am seeing AD2R abend while online job monitoring. Please guide me how to check reason of this abend in the below attached image.

Message : The system or user abend AD2R was issue. From compile unit dsnrcs01 at entry point dsnr24244BAA
DSNRCS01 at compile unit offset +0000F1CA at entry offset +0000F1CA

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zp6C9.png)

I have tried to see reason using offset but am not able to see offset in the above image anywhere.Pls guide me .

Comment: Please show the text of the original abend.  Your image does not provide any useful information

Comment: Since this is an abend in a DB2-module I would first check the DB2 logs for any hints about the original cause of the error.

Answer (score 3):

In your question you're asking about diagnosing by using the offset. However, in this case, that's probably not going to help. The offsets shown will be in the IBM-provided Db2 (DSN...) or CICS (DFH...) libraries, and it's going to be very difficult for you to use those offsets without the listings for those compiled libraries.

Instead, you should approach debugging via the abend code: AD2R.

If you search for that abend code, you'll find its [information page](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cics-ts/6.1?topic=codes-ad2r):

> ## AD2R
>
> ### Explanation
>
> The CICS-DB2 attached TCB connection that processes the DB2 request for this transaction has abended. An exception trace, AP 319D, is written containing the MVS abend code; MVS reason code; and the relevant CICS-DB2 control blocks that are used by the CICS task and by the CICS-DB2 TCB connection. One of the control blocks returned is the CSUB control block. This control block contains data from the MVS SDWA at the time of the abend, for example, the CSB_SDWA_REGS (regs 0-15) and the CSB_SDWA_PSW fields. The CSB_SDWA_REGS is the 16 words following the SDWA eye catcher. The CSB_SDWA_PSW field is the two words following the CSB_SDWA_REGS field.
>
> The TCB connection is terminated if a CICS transaction is forcepurged from CICS when the thread is still active in DB2.
>
> ### System action
>
> The task is abnormally terminated with a CICS transaction dump.
>
> ### User response
>
> Examine the trace in the CICS transaction dump to determine why the CICS-DB2 thread TCB abended.
>
> ### Module
>
> DFHD2EX1

So this instructs you to find out more by investigating the transaction dump that was produced.

Prior to doing that, though, I would suggest you also scan the CICS logs immediately prior to the point where the transaction dump was issued, to determine if there are useful diagnostics printed.